# ERROR at line 1: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("RGAKHAR"."VEHICLE"."VEHICLE_ID")

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to Oracle and would like help on the following :

- I have created a table called Vehicle  which is populated by data from 2 tables : Rentals(master table) and Configuration
- I find the error when I try to insert a value for config_id by selecting data from the table Configuration
- The error says cannot accept null values in Vehicle_Id (which does not have any null values)

*note : Vehicle_Id in the Rentals table is generated by a sequence

```
create table configuration
(config_id int not null,
SEAT NUMBER(2),
2    3    4  DOORS NUMBER(2),
5  LARGE_BAGS NUMBER(2),
SMALL_BAGS NUMBER(2),
Vehicle_Type Varchar2(25),
primary key(config_id));
6    7    8

Table created.

SQL> SQL>
create sequence config_seq start with 1 increment by 1 nocache;

SQL>
Sequence created.

SQL> SQL>
SQL> insert into configuration (seat,doors,large_bags,small_bags,vehicle_type,config_id)
select x.seat,x.doors,x.large_bags,x.small_bags,x.vehicle_type,config_seq.nextval from (select distinct seat,doors,large_bags,small_bags,vehicle_type from rentals) x;
```

2    3

```
12 rows created.

SQL> SQL> SQL> create table Vehicle
(VEHICLE_ID int,
VEHICLE VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
2    3    4  RENTAL_COMMENT CHAR(20),
5  COMPANY_ID int,
config_id int,
Primary key(VEHICLE_ID),
6    7    8  foreign key(company_id) references company(company_id),
9  foreign key(config_id) references configuration(config_id) on delete cascade);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> insert into Vehicle (vehicle_id,vehicle,rental_comment,company_id)
select vehicle_id,vehicle,rental_comment,company_id from rentals;   2

20 rows created.

SQL> insert into vehicle(config_id) select config_id from configuration;
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("RGAKHAR"."VEHICLE"."VEHICLE_ID")
```

Answer (score 2):

What don't you get about the error?  You have defined `vehicle.vehicle` as `NOT NULL`.  Your `insert` looks like:

```
insert into vehicle(config_id)
    select config_id from configuration;
```

The default value for the column is `NULL` and that is not allowed.  You have three choices:

- Specify a value in the `insert`.
- Declare the column so it accepts `NULL` values.
- Provide a `default` value for the column.

It is possible that you want to update the existing rows.  If so, you should just insert the data correctly.  The following is just a possibility on what you intend:

```
insert into Vehicle (vehicle_id, vehicle, rental_comment, company_id, config_id)
    select r.vehicle_id, r.vehicle, r.rental_comment, r.company_id,
           c.config_id
    from rentals r join
         configuration c
         on r.vehicle_type = c.vehicle_type;  -- just a guess
```

Comment: apologies , made an edit - its vehicle.vehicle_id which displays in the error

Comment: @Rohan vehicle.vehicle_id is the primary key, which by definition must be not null. The comments that Gordon has made in his answer re. inserting a row with NOT NULL constraints on one or more columns still stands.

Answer (score 0):

It's not getting `config_id` from configuration please confirm of it and it's also `NOT NULL` column in the `vehicle` table:

So either you can make `config_id` nullable OR provide any default value while inserting in the below statement:

```
insert into vehicle(config_id) select config_id from configuration;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your table Vehicle has not null column VEHICLE. While inserting data using

SQL> insert into vehicle(config_id) select config_id from configuration;

you are not providing all field which are not null.

You need to insert config_id at the time of first input only or use UPDATE query to lator populate config_id

Answer (score 0):

In your note at the bottom, you say:

> Vehicle_Id in the Rentals table is generated by a sequence

I think this is the problem. You think the `vehicle_id` should be populated automatically, why does Oracle complain about `null` for this column?

The words you used indicate that you don't quite understand how it woks. The sequence doesn't generate a value for your column, it only generates a number. It doesn't know what it's for. If you need to use such a number when you insert a new row in the table, you must STILL say so explicitly.

```
insert into vehicle ( vehicle_id, config_id ) select seq_name.nextval, config_id 
                                              from   configuration
```

**However**: You will still have a problem, because the column `vehicle` is also declared `NOT NULL`. You must provide a value for that too, or you will get the same error about a different column. How to solve this depends on your business requirements. (Perhaps that column doesn't need to be NOT NULL in the first place.)